# can the remote app rd web access be accessed from my local system

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I am new to the remote app remote desktop access. I can access the application that i have published from my server using the link FQDN\rdweb. But on trying to access the same url from my local system(outside the server domain, say from my home pc) i get a not found error.

Is there anything that i need to change in my local system to be able to access the remote applications?

Or is it that for accessing webapps i need to be logged into the server? Please help me understand this

Comment: any answers? or is it even possible to achieve what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> access the same url from my local system(outside the server domain, say from my home pc)

Are you trying to access the internal Windows domain of your server from the web/outside your corporate network?

You would need to set up some form of port forwarding (or reverse proxy) on the gateway for your corporate network in order to access the FQDN of the server. Are you able to ping/DNS resolve the FQDN of the server from your home PC?

Conversely, if I've misunderstood your question, please clarify it with seudo-examples of what you're trying to do, complete with sample FQDN/web addresses, and sample IP addresses.